# What is best way to create a weblayout which is cross browser compatible?

Tags: html, css

A design is a very important part of a web site. But making a layout cross browser compatible is very tough task.

What is the easiest way for this?

Comment: I'll open the game by advising you not to build it using IE. Check that it works on IE, but don't use IE while you're writing the HTML.

Comment: Let's not forget html & css validation... doesn't solve everything, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read about browser inconsistencies if you have a reason to be concerned.  Other than that, I would not assume you have a problem unless you observe your pages being rendered differently across browsers.  You should follow ANeves' advice and design in a browser other than IE and then test your pages as you develop.

You can use the tools located [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/04/cross-browser-testing-a-detailed-review-of-tools-and-services/) in an article entitled ["Cross-Browser Testing: A Detailed Review Of Tools And Services"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/06/04/cross-browser-testing-a-detailed-review-of-tools-and-services/) to test that your pages in fact function correctly in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is by writing it and testing in Firefox, and each change I make I run it in IE.  A lot of the times it will be different, but if you keep the changes small and isolate them then each one should be work-aroundable.

After it is completed, I check it in Safari and Chrome, and 99% of the time it's fine.

Also try to avoid tables if you can, learn to use CSS properly and it will save you a lot of time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it´s not that big of a problem. A very good starting point: [CSS Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430223979)

Answer (score 0):

Don't recrate the wheel.  Try finding a website example that works in all browsers and check out it's code.  It might help you out a lot.
For instance, if you want to develop just a layout (header, footer, sidebars, content, containers, menus and things like this)...I sincerely suggest you try different options available online.

For example:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm
http://layouts.ironmyers.com/

You can find a lot of help for this online.  That's only for a LAYOUT. I'm not sure about Visual Effects, I have to fight with each design every time I create a new one.
What works for me is to re-use the things that have worked for me in the past.